# How do I detect a failed download in Chrome using SeleniumBasic?

Tags: vba, google-chrome, selenium

I'm using SeleniumBasic v2.0.9, MS Access 2010, and the Selenium ChromeDriver to automate some file downloads (NB: I need the files from a secured website, I'm not testing my own website).

When I click the "run report" button, a new tab opens in Chrome and it runs a PHP script to generate the report. My code loops looking for the second window to close:

```
this.Driver.FindElementByName(DOWNLOAD_LINK_TEXT).Click
While this.Driver.Windows.Count > 1
  DoEvents
Wend
```

The PHP script generates a unique name for the download, but it's not the name I need for the file, so once I'm back to a single window, I loop looking for the existence of default name (it's a formula `"known part" & randomValue`) before I rename it to what I need.

```
downloadedFile = Dir(this.DestinationPath & defaultFileSpec)
While Len(downloadedFile) = 0
  downloadedFile = Dir(this.DestinationPath & defaultFileSpec)
Wend
```

For the first time, I hit an issue where Chrome notified me that the download failed, but there was no error message in VBA, so, of course, the loop above hung.

[image]

I don't see any properties within the driver that would indicate the success or failure of the download, so how do I detect that the download has failed, preferably *before* launching the infinite loop?

Comment: Just add a timeout to the loop waiting for the file to download so it doesn't try forever.

Comment: Finally got to get back to this, thanks, @JeffC, this is what I ended up doing. If you'd like to make an answer out of that, I'd be happy to reward you with some magical internet points, redeemable for unicorn farts and rainbow slices!

Comment: Added the comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a timeout to the loop waiting for the file to download so it doesn't try forever.